# Breaking subprocess loop from parent process

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is missing here to break the loop in tok2.py from tok1.py?

I try to send a string containing 'exit', read the sent value into my_input and break the loop in tok2.py?

Now tok2 runs forever.

Using Debian 10 Buster with Python 3.7.

tok1.py:

```
import sys
import time
import subprocess

command = [sys.executable, 'tok2.py']
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

i=0
while proc.poll() is None:
    if i > 5:
        #Send 'exit' after 5th iteration
        proc.stdin.write(b'exit')

    print('tok1: '  + str(i))

    time.sleep(0.5)
    i=i+1
```

tok2.py:

```
import sys
import time

ii=0
my_input =''
while True:
    my_input = sys.stdin.read()

    if my_input == b'exit':
        print('tok2: exiting')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        break

    print('tok2: ' + str(ii))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    ii=ii+1    
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: You should look into [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you `Popen` another Python program in the first place? You can import it and run it in another thread.

Comment: perhaps `my_input` ends in a newline character. You might try `.strip()` on it.

Comment: In tok2, print `my_input` so you can see exactly what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `proc.terminate()` to kill the `tok2.py` process, which is logically equivalent to terminating the loop.

Comment: Yes that would work, but in this case the subprocess should end gracefully and finish some work before jumping out of the loop.

Comment: @Rimfire - Good point. I added an additional answer which solves this issue, I think.

Answer (score 0):

As the below answer may not be seen as a "graceful" exit, you could also set an environment variable and check for it.

**tok1.py**

```
import sys
import time
import subprocess
import os

command = [sys.executable, 'tok2.py']
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

i=0
while proc.poll() is None:
    if i > 5:
        #Set 'exit' to 'true' after 5th iteration
        os.environ["EXIT"] = "true"
        proc.terminate()

    print('tok1: '  + str(i))

    time.sleep(0.5)
    i=i+1
```

**tok2.py**

```
import sys 
import time
import os

ii=0
my_input ='' 
while True:
    my_input = sys.stdin.read()

    if os.environ['EXIT'] == "true":
        print('tok2: exiting')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        break

    print('tok2: ' + str(ii))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    ii=ii+1
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: This won't work, setting an environment variable only affects newly-created child processes, not ones that are already running.

Comment: But it does work...? Copy my code and run `python3 tok1.py`. I believe it works because the environment variable is set in the current shell session. It doesn't seem to be connected to child processes.